# Como chamar as telas pelo NavigationDrawerFragment na FragmentActivity?

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma classe que estende `FragmentActivity` para chamar o mapa, e outras classes que são só `Fragment`. Como eu faço o método para chamar as telas pelo `NavigationDrawerFragment`?

Comment: Anderson, poderia incluir o código da sua `Activity` e do `NavigationDrawer` que fez?

Answer (score 1):

No sua classe onde tem o navigation drawer crie um metodo semelhante a este

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
    int title = 0;
    fragment = null;
    boolean withTabs = false;
    switch (position) {
    case 1:
        title = R.string.tipu_title;
        fragment = new MainFragment();
        withTabs = true;
        break;
    }
    if (title != 0) {
        setTitle(title);
    }
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuList);    
    if (position != currentPosition) {
        setCurrentPage(fragment, withTabs);
        currentPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Depois nas classes onde você quer ir para outro fragment é so chamar desse jeito

```
 ((ClasseNavigationDrawer)getActivity()).selectItem(position);
```